# How to make relative path work from another dir?

Tags: python, path

[image: project dir]

In `kek_test_core.py` I have func that imports *all_dev_list.csv* with relative path
I import that .py in parent dir in `kek_test.py`. How can I make `kek_test.py` find *all_dev_list.csv* without changing relative path to absolute, and without changing chdir?

I have already tried adding special_models to `sys.path` - not working
Maybe I can change current dir to list of current dirs or smth like that?

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

Use `importlib.resources.files` to get a `Path` object representing the package.

```
import importlib.resources


csv_file = importlib.resources.files('special_files') / 'all_dev_list.csv'
```

If you've already imported the module, you can pass a reference to it instead of its name.

```
import special_files


csv_file = importlib.resources.files(special_files) / 'all_dev_list.csv'
```

or

```
import special_files as sf

csv_file = importlib.resources.files(sf) / 'all_dev_list.csv'
```